# How to accept Xcode license in a automation way?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

In order to accept the **Xcode License** in CLI, we can run

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Then the console will prompt

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to
>   both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.
>
> Hit the Enter key to view the license agreements at
>   '/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/xcode/7.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf'

By pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the screen will display the license and at the bottom of screen, it prompts

> Software License Agreements Press 'space' for more, or 'q' to quit

By pressing <kbd>q</kbd>, we can quickly mark the license as read, then the final prompt shows up

> By typing 'agree' you are agreeing to the terms of the software license agreements. Type 'print' to print them or anything else to cancel, [agree, print, cancel]

By pressing <kbd>agree</kbd>, the license was finally accepted.

**But the whole process need human's interaction, is there a way to accept the license automatically?**

I tried the following commands, none is work.

```
sudo echo -e "\nq\nagree\n" | sudo xcodebuild -license

sudo echo -e "agree" | sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Can't you set-up Xcode on the machine before using it as a build server?

Comment: have you tried the script found here: https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev-Installer/issues/1

Comment: or better yet does this command work: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -license accept`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It requires admin privileges to do this (so use `sudo` or run as root), but the command `xcodebuild -license accept` worked for me on Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 10):

After run `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` command, you maybe need to restart your software.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't fix that issue from command line, i installed manually (from link below) and that worked for me

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools

Answer (score 0):

I have to

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

and after

```
agree
```